# changing height of numeric updown

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a numeric updown in my application and i want to change the height of the numeric updown i cannot do it from the properties window , i tried to change it using code but still the height is unchanged,is there any way to change the height of the numeric updown either by properties window or by code dynamically. With the default height it is very difficult to change the number using a touch pen(monitor being used is a touch panel)
I am using winforms(.net 4.0)

```
    dynamicUpDown.Width = 200;
    dynamicUpDown.Height = 25;
```

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Try to increase the font size

Comment: @alexm thanks it works write it down as an answer,i'll accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change the height of the Control unless you make it OwnerDraw (I think). Changing the font for this control, and others, will make it bigger in height.

[This](http://www.scribd.com/doc/77858380/250/How-do-I-implement-an-owner-drawn-combobox) link has code which changes the height of an OwnerDrawn `ComboBox`. If you're willing, you may be able to use what you learn from this and apply it to the `NumericUpDown` Control